# URL to REST resource with a composite ID

Tags: api, rest, url

I’m creating a REST API where some of my resources have a composite ID made of two separate parts. An example is a resource for a given latitude and longitude.

My initial thoughts were to add each composite part of the ID as a separate part of the path as per below:

```
http://localhost/phone-details/Vodafone/07123000000 - Operator and number

http://localhost/location-details/50/-2 - Lat and long
```

Is this best practice to take this approach? Should perhaps query strings be used so each composite ID part  has a clear and obvious name? Alternatively should the composite IDs just be passed across separated by a comma?

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest you good book [Restful web services cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596801694.do)
From there (p.77)

> Use the comma ( , ) and semi-colon ( ; ) characters to indicate nonhierarchical portions
> of the URI.
>
> The semicolon convention is used to identify matrix parameters:
>
> http://www.example.org/co-ordinates;w=39.001409,z=-84.578201
> http://www.example.org/axis;x=0,y=9